# touchpad not working at all

Tags: 14.04, touchpad, acer

I installed ubuntu 14.04 on an acer Aspire-E3-112 but my touchpad isn't working at all. It is not reacting as hard as I push or what ever. No idea what could I do. And I never wrote any kind of script by my self.

And I am a newby to the comman line

Comment: go to a terminal and type `uname -a`. this will show you the version. On what kind of hardware are you (is it a thinkpad?)

Comment: #26~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 24 21:16:20 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: And the hardware? (name of the laptop?)

Comment: Aspire-E3-112:~$

Comment: it is an acer product

Comment: I assume, that you understand german (?), take a look at this: http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Touchpad

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> to turn the touchpad on or off (toggle).

Comment: Most likely not the problem.